# No img-responsive in Bootstrap 4

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

I just downloaded the source code for Bootstrap 4 alpha 2 and can't find the class `img-responsive` in it. It exists in Bootstrap 3 source code and I can find it with Notepad++ but in Bootstrap 4s `bootstrap.css` in `dist` folder it doesn't exist.

What happend to it??

Answer (score 87, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images):

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.

Comment: So instead of `img-responsive` we should use `img-fluid`?

Comment: That's correct, it applies the exact same styling as `img-responsive` does in v3.

Comment: So why did they change it if it does the same thing, They just made a breaking change for nothing??

Comment: According to the [alpha 2 changelog](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/12/08/bootstrap-4-alpha-2/): "Renamed .img-responsive to .img-fluid to avoid future confusion on the various responsive image solutions out there."

Answer (score 22):

**Bootstrap 3:**  `.img-responsive`

**Bootstrap 4:**  `.img-fluid`

As in [Bootstrap 4 Images:](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/)

> Images in Bootstrap 4 are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width:
>   100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales
>   with the parent element.

```html
<img class="img-fluid" src="" alt=""> //This will make your image responsive
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need to use a new class img-fluid instead of img-responsive if you are using Bootstrap 4 alpha 2.
Have a look at : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4 you can use class="img-fluid".

This is the explaination:

Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: >auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.

This is the code as suggested: 
`<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">`

Answer (score 2):

Use img-fluid class instead of img-responsive

see [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#images)

Comment: How is this answer any different from the accepted one? What, if anything, does it add?

Answer (score 2):

Boostrap 4 is using `.img-fluid` class.

For more references [Boostrap changes for image](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.img-thumbnail` that is the same of `.img-fluid` but also give an image a rounded 1px border appearance.

Look the result: [Image thumbnails](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#image-thumbnails)