# Image not responsive in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

When I use the `img` tag with a width of 100% on a large screen, the image fits the screen but when the window is resized, there is a horizontal scroll, which shows white spaces and the image doesn’t fit again. All I just want is a fully responsive website but I do not just get it. Please, **what do I do?**

Comment: Please include the code...

Comment: More precisely, a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: Did you use the `img-responsive` class in the `img` tag?

Comment: Greate question. But we'll be glad to answer if yoy can come up with your code

Comment: Check this link will hep you out . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811268/no-img-responsive-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: Use `img-fluid` class on image tag for bootstrap 4

Answer (score 4):

You need to add .img-fluid. From w3schools documentation:

> Create responsive images by adding an .img-fluid class to the <img>
>   tag

Answer (score 2):

If you are using containers and rows then you might also need to contain the image within a div with a class of .col in order to get it to maintain its proportions as it scales, like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="my-image.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

note: the .col class is actually not required but I found it made things align the way I would expect when using containers and rows

Answer (score 0):

use boostrap class

```
.img-fluid
```

or write style

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/

Comment: in BS5, img-fluid class does not work in some cases but a custom class with { max-width: 100%; height: auto; } always works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use .img-fluid instead of .img-responsive class in Bootstrap 4.
 Example(Below):

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="your_image.jpg" alt="Image">
```